# Developing RESTful web service, can I depend on PUT and DELETE to be available?

Tags: web-services, apache, drupal, nginx, httprequest

While developing a RESTful web service for Drupal, I found out my own development server (running nginx) actually blocks DELETE and PUT HTTP requests.
While for me it was simple to solve this problem, I wonder whether it will actually be a smart decision to depend on PUT/DELETE requests.
My development will be free to use and install in any Drupal installation, which can be on shared servers, on Apache, nginx, or any other stack.

Can I take into account that PUT and DELETE will be accepted on most of the standard Drupal installations ?
What is the standard and the common configuration for web servers and the firewalls that sits before them - to allow PUT/DELETE, or not ?

Comment: I have never heard of those verbs being blocked by default. Please elaborate on how they were disabled and what you did you solve it.

Comment: My installation wasn't a simple one, it is an aegir installation from long time ago. Still, DELETE and PUT weren't enabled by default, so I want to be sure what is the default behavior...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PUT and DELETE are enabled by default in Apache, Nginx and Lighttp. They are part of the HTTP standard, which any major web server will support. You can rely on them for the vast majority of Drupal installations.